# Backward ssh connection via Forward https connection (https-tunnel)

Tags: ssh, nginx, socket, https, tunneling

I need a construction that make possible to tunnel backward SSH via forward HTTPS. I tried to draw on a picture what I have to get. The picture shows 4 steps that explain what and how I want to make.
[image: picture]

How it can be done? Is there a ready solution maybe?

Comment: Upvote just for including a nice picture. Can you add some clarification? It's not clear to me what you are trying to do or from which machine. Is it that you are trying issue a command on Server that will `ssh` to `Remote host` and create a tunnel on `Remote host` such that some traffic on `Remote host` is passed through the tunnel to some service on `Server`?

Comment: The purpose of HTTPS connection is only to create a tunnel. And SSH client from Server may connect to the Remote host only through HTTPS-tunnel. So the Server can administrates Remote host by SSH via HTTPS-tunnel only.